# How to print Array content as String in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing

How can the `Array` content be converted to a `String` in Java?

Example:

```
int[] myArray = {1,2,3};
```

The output has to be:

```
"123"
```

`Arrays.toString(myArray)` is returning:

```
"[1, 2, 3]"
```

and `myArray.toString()`, returns:

```
[I@12a3a380
```

So none of them works. Is there a function for this?

This question might look similar to [(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array), but is actually different. I am literally asking for a `String` made of all the array entries.

Comment: you don't want the array converted to a String. you want the elements converted to String, and then concatenated. I think iterating over the array would be the easiest way to implement this

Comment: `IntStream.of(myArray).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(joining(""))`.

Comment: @Zabuza it doesn;t work.. Compile will fail...!!

Comment: @AndyTurner `IntStream.of(myArray)` just calls `Arrays.stream` internally... and I don't think this is a duplicate on how to *print* the contents of an array, this does not look like a duplicate to me

Comment: "_Is there a function that does what I am trying to do without looping through the array and do it manually?_" no because this would not make much sense to provide a method that "specific". You could do it with a `String` array with `String.join`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
String joined = Arrays.stream(myArray)
            .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));

System.out.println(joined);
```

Answer (score 7):

The old-fashioned way:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int value : myArray) {
  builder.append(value);
}
... now use builder.toString()
```

Less fancy compared to the stream solution, but on the other hand: in case runtime performance matters, this here should beat any other approach.

Answer (score 6):

A curveball approach is to remove any non-digit character from the ouput of one of the traditional serialization methods:

```
Arrays.toString(myArray).replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

which yields `123` in your example.

[`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) replaces all positive matches of the regular expression in the first parameter with the contents of the second parameter. `\D` is [regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for anything that is not a digit.

Comment: @Eugene: I would throw a hissy fit if I found this in actual code somewhere. :)

Comment: And I always thought only Perl knows TIMTOWTDI ... my vote as well you got.

Answer (score 3):

I will go old school, which works every time no matter what as follows:

```
String myString = "";
for(int val : myArray)
{
  myString += val;
}

System.out.println(myString); // To check the output of myString
```

Will work! Hope this helps!

**Note**: This will work in Embedded Java as well where StringBuilder and some other classes are stripped for embedded devices.

Comment: `StringBuilder`s should generally be preferred where multiple appends are being made to a single target, for better performance. See GhostCat's answer above.

Comment: I am aware of that. @GaurangTandon

Comment: This approach is essentially the same as the one proposed by ghostcat, sans the use of `StringBuilder` for memory efficiency.